# How to add tab in console2

Tags: terminal, console2

I am using Console 2 in Windows. I have two different working directory. One is for php and mysql [e\wamp\www] related projects and the other is for frontend projects (angular , React)[e\frontend].

When I open a new tab is open at the php project directory. How can I add New tab with the frontend project directory. Its possible to go to the directory by using cd. Though I want create a different tab with some different style for frontend projects.

Comment: Configure your tabs as appropriate. See [Console2: Powershell, Command Prompt, Ruby, Python and Nodejs - Amido](https://amido.com/blog/console2-powershell-command-prompt-ruby-python-and-nodejs/) for instructions.